# Making addToCart and cart page execute synchronously in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, addtocart

I am a complete newbie in magento, javascript and php

So I am using magento 1 and my checkout page takes around 1 sec and cart page takes around 1.5 sec to load

I want to decrease the time these two pages take to load.

I researched about this but found nothing. So the only option I can think of is to somehow make them run synchronously.

But I am not getting how I can make them synchronous. I researched about this for 4 to 5 hours now but found nothing.

Is there a way to make them run synchronously? Or is there any other way to reduce their execution time by half?

Comment: Pages loading in 1 sec considered as fast

Comment: @RintoGeorge the cart page opens in 3 to 4 sec after clicking addToCart button and this happens when there is only one user. When there is load on the website it will get worser. If I am able to reduce the time even by 0.5 to 1 seconds it will be still okay.